# System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out error?

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0

I have a thread class which makes a web request. After 20-30 urls request, its throwing exception: System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out.
My code is below where it is throwing exception:

```
httpReq.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        httpReq.KeepAlive = false;
        httpReq.Headers.Add("Location", "");
        httpReq.Timeout = this.HttpRequestTimeout;

        httpRes = (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.GetResponse();
```

In last line : httpRes = (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.GetResponse();
it is throwing exception.
"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

I am using session for setting some values with the request header.

Comment: Are you sending the request to different url's/host's? Does the url's you try actually work?

Comment: Thanx for reply, yes urls are different,and all of them are working...

Comment: Some urls are same and some different but all are comming from same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. I was not using  httpRes.close() method after using response object. That's why after 80-90 request it was returning : "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden ".